# Is it possible to see user uploaded images while reviewing edits on a post?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

While reviewing an edit I stumble upon bunch of additions that include some  uploaded images. The editing user wanted to improve the answer by including some images but the image links don't get substituted by actual images. Although I can just copy the links one by one and view in a new tab but that makes it tedious. Is there any way I could see the parsed output in which the images would show in-line rather than just as a link or custom tag?[image]

Comment: You are merely looking at the *markdown diff* of the change. Try switching the diff view from “markdown” to “rendered” at the top....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can click on "rendered output" to see the rendered post, including any images.

[image]